# How to calculate Critical Values of the F-Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to program a function to calculate the critical values for the F-Distribution, I mean the values from the tables, for example $F_{1,1}(0.95) = 161.45$. I was looking in the Abramowitz & Stegun Handbook of Mathematical Function, and I found this aproximation 
$$
x =  \frac{\sqrt{2v_{2}-1}\frac{v_{1}}{v_{2}}F\sqrt{2v_{1}-1}}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{v_{1}}{v_{2}}}F}
$$-

but I think this is not giving me the value I need, or maybe I not using this right, I'm not sure. So, what is the right way to calculate the critical values?

Answer (score 0):

You can find FORTRAN90-code in the library [CDFLIB90](https://biostatistics.mdanderson.org/SoftwareDownload/SingleSoftware.aspx?Software_Id=21). It seems to be done by calculating the incomplete beta integral. This is the reference mentioned therein:

DiDinato, A. R. and Morris,  A.   H.  Algorithm 708: Significant Digit Computation of the Incomplete  Beta  Function Ratios.  ACM Trans. Math.  Softw. 18 (1993), 360-373.

Or you can download the sources of the famous open statistic software called [R](http://www.cran.r-project.org/). There the F-quantiles seem to be computed within some function `C_qf` Unfortunately, if you install R and run `?qf` you will not get the direct reference to the original journal paper. (With the other distributions I was interested in, it worked.)